# Android : BitmapFactory.options inMutable before API level 11

Tags: android

Am using [BitmapFactory.options inMutable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inMutable) variable. But this seems to be supported only from API level 11. What do I do for those users using the previous API Levels?

Answer (score 1):

On API's below 11 you will need to [copy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copy(android.graphics.Bitmap.Config,%20boolean)) the `Bitmap` with the `mutable` argument set to true:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resource, R.drawable.myDrawable);
Bitmap copy = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

You will probably want to fiddle a bit around with the arguments.